# UK Appendix FM Income Thresholds and Children

Tags: united-kingdom, family

The current income threshold specified in [Appendix FM](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/chapter-8-appendix-fm-family-members) is £18,600. And there is an increment added to the threshold for each dependent child.

In the case where the *sponsor* has children from a previous marriage or relationship, does the increment need to be applied for these? Or is it applied only for children of the primary applicant?

Answer (score 1):

If the sponsor's children are UK citizens or have permanent residence in the UK, then they are not considered. Also if the children are EEA nationals, they do not count towards the support requirements. [Reference here](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/525708/Appendix_FM_1_7_Financial_Requirement.pdf) (section 2.8).

Comment: Do you have a source/reference for this?

Comment: Edited with the source/reference.

Answer (score 1):

This is no longer the case. As of now, changes to the immigration rules take effect...

> The provisions on minimum income thresholds are amended so that these
>   have to be met in respect of all relevant children, that is, to
>   include any dependent child of the applicant’s parent’s partner as
>   well as the applicant’s parent.  This applies to applications made on
>   or after 24 November 2016.

See [Statement of Changes in the Immigration Rules](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/564933/57079_-_HC_667_-_Web_Accessible.pdf)